# Text area validation max rule not working in laravel 6

Tags: php, html, forms, xampp, laravel-6

I'm try to use `max` rule set to 2000 in `textarea`, but I put more than 2000 character the validation is not work for other input fields and the **page reload with empty input value** the problem still even when I try the number of character less then 2000, when I hit add with empty `textarea` the required validate is work, I had try also to change max to size and still same problem.

I want to validate `textarea` with old input value back in next request and if number of character more then 2000 display the error message.
I can use `javascript` or `maxlength` attribute in html but want to do it from server side.

**The validation failed for all input when `textarea` have 974 characters**

- **Laravel version 6**
- **Xampp version 3.2.4**
- **Php version 7.3.9**

**Blade**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('problems.store', auth()->user()) }}">
    @csrf
    <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">{{ __('Problem information') }}</h6>

    <div class="pl-lg-4">
        <!-- alert -->
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
    @endif

    <!-- Account Number input -->
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('Account_Number') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label"
                   for="input-account-number">{{ __('Account Number') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">

                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                </div>

                <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('Account_Number') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                       placeholder="{{ __('Account Number') }}" type="text" name="Account_Number"
                       value="{{ old('Account_Number') }}" autofocus>
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('Account_Number'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Account_Number') }}</strong>
                                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <!-- Account Name input -->
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('Account_Name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label"
                   for="input-account-name">{{ __('Account Name') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">

                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-id-card"></i></span>
                </div>

                <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('Account_Name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                       placeholder="{{ __('Account Name') }}" type="text" name="Account_Name"
                       value="{{ old('Account_Name') }}" autofocus>
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('Account_Name'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Account_Name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <!-- Email input -->
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                       placeholder="{{ __('Email') }}" type="email" name="email"
                       value="{{ old('email') }}">
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                 </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <!-- Date input -->
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('Date') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-data">{{ __('Date') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('Date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                       placeholder="{{ __('Date') }}" type="date" name="Date" value="{{ old('Date') }}"
                       min="2005-01-01" max="2025-12-31" autofocus>
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('Date'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Date') }}</strong>
                 </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <!-- problem description input -->
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('problem_descrip') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label"
                   for="input-problem-description">{{ __('Problem Description') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></span>
                </div>

                <!-- the problem here -->
                <textarea class="form-control{{ $errors->has('problem_descrip') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                        name="problem_descrip" rows="2"
                        placeholder="{{ __('Descrip the problem here') }}">{{ old('problem_descrip') }}</textarea>

            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('problem_descrip'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('problem_descrip') }}</strong>
                 </span>
            @endif
        </div>


        <!-- added by input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-added_by">{{ __('Added By') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #e9ecef"><i lass="fas fa-user-tie"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="my-4"/>
        <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">{{ __('Solved') }}</h6>
        <!-- Comment input -->
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-comment">{{ __('Comment') }}</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-comment"></i></i></span>
                </div>
                <textarea class="form-control{{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                          name="comment" rows="2"
                          placeholder="{{ __('comment on the problem or solution') }}">{{ old('comment') }}</textarea>
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</strong>
                 </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <!-- added by input -->

        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-added_by">{{ __('Solved By') }}</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #e9ecef"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" disabled>
        </div>

        <!-- Solved checkbox -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
            <div class="input-group{{ $errors->has('Sovled') ? ' has-danger' : '' }} mb-2">
                <input type='hidden' value='0' name='Sovled'>
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="Sovled" value="1"
                       type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">{{ __('Solved') }}</label>
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('Sovled'))
                <span class="text-danger ml--4" role="alert">
                    <b>{{ $errors->first('Sovled') }}</b>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <!-- submit button -->
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">{{ __('Add') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

**method used in controller**

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $rules = [
        'Account_Number' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        'Account_Name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:20'],
        'Date' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d'],
        'problem_descrip' => ['required', 'min:1', 'max:2000'], // max not work 
        'comment' => ['nullable', 'string', 'required_if:Sovled,1', 'min:0', 'max:2000'], // something
        'Sovled' => ['nullable', 'numeric', new Checkbox($request->get('comment'), $request->get('Sovled'))]
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'comment.required_if' => 'The :attribute field can not be blank when solved box is checked you need to write the solution.'
    ];

    $result = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $customMessages);

    if ($result->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($result)->withInput($request->input());
    }

    dd($request->all());

    //$request->user->id
}
```

---

**The Problem**

[image]

Comment: Reading this page https://laravel-news.com/testing-length-validation-laravel they use | to separate rules instead of ', '  something like: **'problem_descrip' => ['required|min:1|max:2000']**

Comment: @Triby Thank you my dear this way problem_descrip' => ['required|min:1|max:2000'] not work it is give me an error I have try this problem_descrip' => 'required|min:1|max:2000' but still have same problem I have read testing length page but I cannot find an answer or solution there. I want to know why this happened.

Comment: Try this `'problem_descrip' => 'required|min:1| max:2000', // max not work`

Comment: @Omi something I try also to clear browser cach still have same problem.

Comment: any other rules are working?

Comment: @Omi yes all work except max in ```textarea``` when have value in it non of validation rules is work especially text is long .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a session problem, try changing session driver from cookie to file in `.env`

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, You Must Add Of Aliases **STRING**, Because Max Detected For Size Of File. Good Luck, Please UP Button If Helping Your Problem :).

```
$rules = [
    'Account_Number' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    'Account_Name' => ['required', 'string'],
    'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:20'],
    'Date' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d'],
    'problem_descrip' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:2000'], //Add string here
    'comment' => ['nullable', 'string', 'required_if:Sovled,1', 'min:0', 'max:2000'], // something
    'Sovled' => ['nullable', 'numeric', new Checkbox($request->get('comment'), $request->get('Sovled'))]
];
```

Comment: The problem was from template I use .